# SELECT all values between two values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Lets say i have a table that has the following columns
(Start, End, Interval)

Is there any way to get all values between Start, End with the interval each on one row?
Notice that will be more then one row in the (Start, End, Interval) table but they should not overlap.

If possible without loops/cursors/temp tables/variable tables.

Sample data

```
Start           End        Interval
1               3          1
9               12         1
16              20         2
```

Desired outcome:

```
Result
1
2
3
9
10
11
12
16
18
20
```

Comment: Do not understand your wording, can you rephrase the question?

Comment: Could you provide example input data and desired output?

Comment: Changed the text and added a example of the input values and the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great use case for a recursive common table expression:

```
;with cte as (
    select [Start] as Result, [End], [Interval]
    from Table1
    union all
    select Result + [Interval], [End], [Interval]
    from cte
    where Result + [Interval] <= [End]
)
select Result
from cte
order by Result
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55732/2)</kbd>**

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```sql
WITH tally AS (
  SELECT 0 n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 FROM tally WHERE n < 100 -- adjust 100 to a max possible value for (end - start) / interval
)
SELECT start + n * [interval] result
  FROM Table1 t CROSS JOIN tally n
 WHERE n.n <= (t.[end] - t.start) / t.[interval]
 ORDER BY result
```

**Note:** If you do a lot of such queries you may consider to substitute the recursive CTE `tally` with a persisted numbers table `tally` with a primary key on `n` column.

Output:

```
| RESULT |
|--------|
|      1 |
|      2 |
|      3 |
|      9 |
|     10 |
|     11 |
|     12 |
|     16 |
|     18 |
|     20 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bcb970/6)** demo

Comment: if you know HINDI then "Man Gaye Ustad"

Comment: Love the example and you where first, but you hardcoded the max limit @RomanPekar did not thats why i picked his solution

Answer (score 1):

I know you have accepted the answer, I think this is also correct.

**[Fiddle demo 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bcb970/32)**;

```
select x.number
from master..spt_values x cross join table1 t
where x.type='p' and x.number between t.[start] and t.[end]
                 and x.number % t.[interval] = 0
```

Results:

```
| NUMBER |
|--------|
|      1 |
|      2 |
|      3 |
|      9 |
|     10 |
|     11 |
|     12 |
|     16 |
|     18 |
|     20 |
```

**EDIT:** If you want to go unlimited numbers try this approach and cross join more Digits table as required. This example goes up to 9999.

**[Fiddle demo 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07b6a/6)**:

```
;WITH Digits AS (
    select Digit 
    from ( values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) 
          AS t(Digit))
,Numbers AS (
    select u.Digit + t.Digit*10 + h.Digit*100 + th.Digit*1000 as number
    from Digits u
    cross join Digits t
    cross join Digits h
    cross join Digits th
    --Add more cross joins as required
    )

Select number
From Numbers x cross join table1 t
where x.number between t.[start] and t.[end]
      and x.number % t.[interval] = 0;
Order by number
```

Comment: this did not work, the values between the values where missing... (10,11,18)

Comment: The interval is set to 2 thats why i didn't want 17 if you look its also skipping 19..

Comment: This worked great but be aware that your depending on master..spt_values and it only contains 2164 different values in the number field, if you use values bigger/smaller then a certain value it could return the wrong result.. negative values are a great example of where it would fail!

Comment: Yes I agree but [check this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07b6a/1), second query is accepted answer (I like that too) but it breaks before this. Reason is maximum possible recursion is 100 by default.

Comment: thanks a lot for this warning this could be a problem! found a solution add the following to your select "option (maxrecursion 0)"

Comment: Yes you can do that too but by default it is 100 for a reason. No problem you got few solutions and aware of the issue. Mind you recursion is costly. But anyways, Good luck !